# What solution should be used for implementing single sign on for a ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, forms-authentication, identity

We have 3-4 ASP.Net MVC 5 applications for which we want to implement the solution of single sign on.

Our requirements are

1. Any user trying to access anyone of the application (any page)
   and if he has not signed in into the same or another application in
   the same browser should be re-directed to the login page.
2. If the login is successful till that application is running, the user
   should not be asked the login credentials again.
3. If the user logs out from one application, he should log out from all other
   applications

Things which may be useful while suggesting a solution.

1. Currently 2 applications are hosted on different domains. Other 2 applications are on subdomains
2. Though they are on the same server, one application can have access to database of other application but we would like to have a solution where in this direct access of db should not be required.
3. We would like to have a 5th application which will do the account management and also login and logout will be handled by this application
4. We are not just looking at a solution where authentication will be done by the identity server but we are also looking at the authorization wherein the identity server will authorize the level of access of requesting application.
5. Going ahead if this solution can help us take care of mobile devices as well as webservice based client access, it would be an added bonus.
6. We are using forms authentication in our application right now.

We have seen some examples on internet which but we seem to be lost on some or the other feature. Either we are going wrong somewhere or we are not looking in the right direction.

Hence we are looking for an answer. Appreciate your time to read this big question.

Thanks